# Remove duplicated elements from list

Tags: r, list, redundancy

I have a `list` of `character` `vector`s:

```
my.list <- list(e1 = c("a","b","c","k"),e2 = c("b","d","e"),e3 = c("t","d","g","a","f"))
```

And I'm looking for a `function` that for any `character` that appears more than once across the `list`'s `vector`s (in each `vector` a `character` can only appear once), will only keep the first appearance.

The result list for this example would therefore be:

```
res.list <- list(e1 = c("a","b","c","k"),e2 = c("d","e"),e3 = c("t","g","f"))
```

Note that it is possible that an entire `vector` in the `list` is eliminated so that the number of elements in the resulting `list` doesn't necessarily have to be equal to the input `list`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We can `unlist` the `list`, get a logical `list` using `duplicated` and extract the elements in 'my.list' based on the logical index

```
un <- unlist(my.list)
res <- Map(`[`, my.list, relist(!duplicated(un), skeleton = my.list))
identical(res, res.list)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative using `mapply` with `setdiff` and `Reduce`.

```
# make a copy of my.list
res.list <- my.list
# take set difference between contents of list elements and accumulated elements
res.list[-1] <- mapply("setdiff", res.list[-1],
                                  head(Reduce(c, my.list, accumulate=TRUE), -1))
```

Keeping the first element of the list, we compute on subsequent elements and the a list of the cumulative vector of elements produced by `Reduce` with `c` and the `accumulate=TRUE` argument. `head(..., -1)` drops the final list item containing all elements so that the lengths align.

This returns

```
res.list
$e1
[1] "a" "b" "c" "k"

$e2
[1] "d" "e"

$e3
[1] "t" "g" "f"
```

Note that in `Reduce`, we could replace `c` with `function(x, y) unique(c(x, y))` and accomplish the same ultimate output.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solutions here very complex for my understanding and sought a simpler technique. Suppose you have the following list.

```
my_list <- list(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,5), b = c(1,2,2,3,3,4,4), 
                
                d = c("Mary", "Mary", "John", "John"))
```

The following much simpler piece of code removes the duplicates.

```
sapply(my_list, unique)
```

You will end up with the following.

```
$a
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$b
[1] 1 2 3 4

$d
[1] "Mary" "John"
```

There is beauty in simplicity!

Comment: This is not what was asked by the OP.